# Dataset with more than three values

Tags: dataset, weka, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am planning to create a recommender system using **apache Mahout**.
I searched on internet about it. and i found it uses the following format for dataset file.
**userId, itemId, preference**

what i want to use as a dataset have structure like this.

**Id, rating, location, skills, fee**

Is there any way i can do this?
Or i have to use **Weka**
It provides the option of creating custom dataset. but reviews suggest that it is not a good option as compared to mahout for Recommender system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to do collaborative filtering? Usually with CF you take in lots of user preferences about items. Then for a given user you recommend items. You don't seem to have user preferences.

In any case you will need to preprocess your data into the form required, it is all that will be used in CF anyway.

Comment: i am planning hybrid approach. collaborative and content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understend this exemple:

https://github.com/apache/mahout/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/example/bookcrossing

i hope it will help you